# What is the difference between M420 S and M420 S1?

Tags: marlin, g-code, bed-leveling

I have been reading through the Marlin website about ABL (Auto Bed Leveling)  and I see what appears to be conflicting information.

At https://marlinfw.org/docs/features/auto_bed_leveling.html it states that running `G28` (Auto Home) will turn off ABL and that to reactivate it you need to insert the code `M420 S1`.

However at https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/G029-mbl.html it states:

> `G28` disables bed leveling. Follow with `M420 S` to turn leveling on, or
>   use `RESTORE_LEVELING_AFTER_G28` to automatically keep leveling on after
>   `G28`

The latter is referring mostly to manual bed leveling, but in this section is referring to ABL.

So what is the difference between the `S` and the `S1` options?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### TL;DR

**Short answer**: "There is no difference!".

---

**Long answer**

G-code is parsed line by line. The parser in the firmware reads the command and the options (also called parameters) following it, comments are discarded.

Therefore, option `S` should be followed by a Boolean value `0` for False or `1` for True. Without a value it is undefined and should be reported as incorrect or treated as false (in my opinion). But, the developers have chosen differently. If a Boolean value is expected and the value is not given, the parameter is parsed as `true`. This has analogy with other software options or switches like e.g. used by Linux commands.

This means that for Marlin  the G-code `M420 S` is exactly the same as `M420 S1`.

*I've checked this with another command (this is not depending on the G-code command as there is a single parser processiong the G-codes and the following parameters); `M211` where `M211 S` is exactly the same as `M211 S1`*.